# remove() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a 'detect typing'-function for a chat program.

Everything works regarding detection of when a user is typing or sending a message, but `$("#"+data.person+"").remove();` does not work.

The console is printing "is typing function stopped - remove", so it should work.

**Any suggestions to what I am missing?** Also, please let me know if I should add more code. I am just assuming that this is enough to get an idea of what is going on.

**Client-side**

```js
var myUserName;
var myUserPassword;
var myUserID;
var currentConversation;
var conversationInvite;


$(document).ready(function() {
 var socket = io.connect("localhost:3000");
    var typing = false;  
    var timeout = undefined;

    function timeoutFunction() {  
            typing = false;
            socket.emit("typing", false, currentConversation);
          }



$(document).on('pageshow', '#chat', function(e,data){   
    $('.chatContent').height(getRealContentHeight()); 
});

function getRealContentHeight() {
 var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
 var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
 var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
 var viewport_height = $(window).height();

 var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
 if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
  content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
 } 
 return content_height;
}


//-----Chat
 // Sending the message 
        $("#msg").keypress(function(e){
          var msg = $("#msg").val();
          if (e.which === 13) {
            if (msg.trim() == "") {
              return;
            } else {
                var timeInMs = Date.now();

                function fulldate(date) {
                  var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                  'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
                  return months[date.getUTCMonth()] + ' ' + date.getUTCDate() + ', ' + date.getUTCFullYear();
                }

                var message = {
                 message_id: currentConversation,
                 message_sender: myUserName,
                   message_body: msg,
                   time: timeInMs,
                   date: fulldate(new Date(timeInMs))
                };
                socket.emit("send message", message, currentConversation);
                $("#msg").val("");
                $("#msg").focus();

                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeoutFunction();
            }
          } else if (e.which !== 13) {
                if (typing === false && $("#msg").is(":focus")) {
                    typing = true;
                    socket.emit("typing", true, currentConversation, myUserName);
                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 3000);
                } else {
                    console.log("Timeout function started");
                    //clearTimeout(timeout);
                    timeoutFunction();
                }
            }
        });


        socket.on("isTyping", function(data) {  
            if (data.isTyping) {
              if ($("#"+data.person+"").length === 0) {
                $(".chatContent").append("<div id='"+ data.person +"'><span class='grey'>" + data.person + " is typing...</div>");
                timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 5000);
                console.log(data.person);
              }
            } else {
             console.log(data.person);
               $("#"+ data.person +"").remove();
               console.log("is typing function stopped - remove");
              }
          });

});
```

**Server-side**

```js
 // Detect typing
    socket.on("typing", function(data, currentConversation, myUserName) {  
        socket.broadcast.to(currentConversation).emit("isTyping", {isTyping: data, person: myUserName});
        console.log("Someone is typing");
    });
```

Comment: have you tried to use `console.log(data.person)` and check the value

Comment: also check html generated by inspecting!

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen please see my updated code. As you can see it prints the correct name the first time, but in the 'else' function it prints undefined. What could be the problem?

Comment: If it prints Undefined, how does you guess it should remove something

Comment: Yes I see that it makes sense, but my questions is, why is it undefined in the first place?

Comment: If your function is in document.ready(), and $("#"+data.person+"") is an id which is added dynamically (after the document was loaded), it will be undefined.

Comment: but it is not undefined when it is added, which is after the document is loaded

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: It is not a fiddle, but I have added all the necessary code in my question. Hope it is enough

Comment: So I've found out that the problems lies in the `myUserName` because if I remove it from this `socket.emit("typing", true, currentConversation, myUserName);` then it "works". The div is removed when it should, however now it just says "undefined is typing...". This is obviously NOT the solution

Answer (score 0):

The else clause is executed as a result of the timeout function.  What is the result of adding console.log(currentConversation) to the timeout function? Are you certain that, when the timeout function is being called that the html element already exists? To test for that, you could do the following, assuming data.person is correctly populated.

```
if($("#"+data.person).length){ console.log(data.person+" html id exists."); }
else {console.log(data.person+" html element does not exist.");}
```

Inserting your logic in the first clause would successfully execute the remove statement where it's not needed in the second because the element no longer exists.